# Create Prolog Vocabulary

Tags: prolog, circuit

I am quite new to prolog, and I have some basic questions...

I don't know if "vocabulary" is the right world in English, but I need to create one to describe an electronic circuit.

My problem is, how do I create these functions and how I use the "=" statement since prolog doesn't seems do accept it?

I'm using SWI Prolog.

That's what I have to put in prolog:

Decide the vocabulary (Predicates, functions, constants):

Ports are represented by constants (X1, X2, ...) –

Gate(X1)

Type(X1) = Xor – types: AND, OR, XOR or NOT

Circuits(C1)

Terminals(x) – returns inputs and outputs of x

In(1, X1) – function that returns first input of X1

Out – function that returns output

Arity(c, i, j) – function, circuit c has i inputs and j outputs

Connected(Out(1, X1), In(1, X2)) - which ports are connected

Signal(t) – signal value for terminal t.

That's what I tried until now. I don't think my approach to the "=" is right...

```
gate(x1).
gate(x2).
gate(a1).
gate(a2).
gate(o1).
type(x1, xor).
type(x2, xor).
type(a1, and).
type(a2, and).
type(o1, or).
circuit(c1).
```

Should i use an predicate named Equal(X, Y) ?, like "equal (type(x1), xor).

How should I implement these?

```
Gate(X1) , Type(X1) = XOR
Gate(X2) , Type(X2) = XOR
Gate(A1) , Type(A1) = AND
Gate(A2) , Type(A2) = AND
Gate(O1) , Type(O1) = OR
```

I don't know how to continue from here. All my approaches trying to implement the functions seems to be wrong (can't consult).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this document](http://akira.ruc.dk/~henning/kiis08/coursematerial/coursenote.pdf) to get some inspiration :)

For instance, basic *functions* (i.e. gates) can be described like

```
and(0, 0, 0).
and(0, 1, 0).
and(1, 0, 0).
and(1, 1, 1).

xor(0, 0, 0).
...
```

and then combined to get more complex building blocks

```
fulladder(A, B, Carryin, Sum, Carryout):-
 xor(A, B, X),
 and(A, B, Y),
 and(X, Carryin, Z),
 xor(Carryin, X, Sum),
 or(Y, Z, Carryout).
```

that *compute* the logic function:

```
?- fulladder(X, Y, Z, 0, 1).
X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 1 ? ;
X = 1, Y = 0, Z = 1 ? ;
X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 0 ? ;
no
```

Comment: youre saying that i should start with general rules first, then codify a instance of the problem right? i think that "vocabulary" doesnt needs to be inserted in the .pro file, and i should start with general rules. But how i implement lines ta use the "="? Like, gate(x1) , type(x1) = xor. (x1 is a gate and x1 is a xor)

Comment: In Prolog, use pattern matching: `?- gate(Name), type(Name, Type).` will provide in Type (note - uppercase symbols are **variables**) the Type of Name. That is, you **already** assigned the type of `x1` to be `xor` in the Prolog fragment you show.